# EIGRP Auto-summary

Tags: cisco, routing, protocol-theory, eigrp

One more question about EIGRP,

EIGRP auto-summary what is the impact on the network ? i was reading about but it was not clear for me.

And why is it a good Cisco practice to be disabled ?

I am studying for my CCNA and i really want to a have a good understanding of all topics, so apologies for my basic questions.

Comment: Luckily, EIGRP auto-summarization is off by default, these days - one tripwire gone, finally :-) https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios/iproute_eigrp/command/reference/ire_book/ire_a1.html#wp1062919

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Auto-summary summarizes network advertisements based on classful boundaries.  Since classful addressing has been obsolete since before you were born, it's good practice to disable it.